# SwiftUI: adding a View at the top of a dynamic List causes the View to shrink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple `SwiftUI` list that displays numbers asynchronously from a `Combine` publisher, when I add a `View` at the top of the list to act as a header view, I face a weird *shrink* or *flicker* happens for the header at the time the `Content View` gets redrawn when the data returns from the publisher:

here's the view-model class that has the publisher:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Int] = []
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
            (0...10)
            .publisher
            .delay(for: .seconds(3), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main) //to simulate async call
            .sink { (value) in
            self.items.append(value)
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

and here's the `ContentView` struct that interacts with the above view model:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {

        List {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                Text("Some Text")
                Text("Some Other Very Long Text Some Other Some Other Long Text")
            }
            .background(Color.red)

            ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) {  item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the result:

[image]

I've tried to separate the `VStack` at the top of the list into an external `View` but nothing changed.

what's causing this weird shrink and is there a way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to use explicit list rows inset, something like as below...

```
List {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
        Text("Some Text")
        Text("Some Other Very Long Text Some Other Some Other Long Text")
    }
    .background(Color.red)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

    ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) {  item in
        Text("\(item)")
    }
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)
}
```

Comment: this is an excellent workaround, you answered the first part of the question, but why's this happening ? is this a big in SwiftUI ?

Comment: @JAHelia, It looks like a bug, but I'm not sure. You can send feedback to Apple, they can tell definitely.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work for me. I ended up using TableViewController instead.