# Swiftui - Padding is changing when using navigationlink to open another view

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

This is a slightly odd issue I'm running into. The best way to explain it is to show you. You can see with this video, https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCFK2.jpg. What's causing this?

I'm also getting this message at the same time.

[Assert] displayModeButtonItem is internally managed and not exposed for DoubleColumn style. Returning an empty, disconnected UIBarButtonItem to fulfill the non-null contract.

This is the first view you see.

```
var body: some View {
    
    let income = getIncome()
    let expenses = getExpenses()
    let difference = income - expenses

    NavigationView {

        List {
            Text(getGreeting())
                .font(.title2)
            
            Section(header: Text("Stats")) {
                let incomeTransactions = transactions.filter({$0.kind == TransactionType.income.rawValue})
                let expenseTransactions = transactions.filter({$0.kind == TransactionType.expense.rawValue})
                
                NavigationLink(destination: StatDetailView(title: "Income", balance: income.round(), transactions: incomeTransactions, month: now.month, user: $user)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Income")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$\(income.round())")
                            .foregroundColor(.brg)
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: StatDetailView(title: "Expenses", balance: expenses.round(), transactions: expenseTransactions, month: now.month, user: $user)){
                    HStack {
                        Text("Expenses")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$\(expenses.round())")
                            .foregroundColor(.darkRed)
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Difference")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$\(difference.round())")
                        .foregroundColor(income < expenses ? .darkRed : .brg)
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Accounts")) {
                
                ForEach(user.accounts, id: \.self) { account in
                    HStack {
                        Text(account.fullName)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$\(account.balance.round())")
                            .foregroundColor((account.kind == Account.Kind.credit.rawValue) ? .darkRed : .brg) //Set credit account balance to red since you owe that money
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Categories")) {
                ForEach(user.categories, id: \.self) { category in
                    HStack {
                        Text(category.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$\(getCategoryAmount(category: category).round())")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .navigationTitle(now.month)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {showSettings.toggle()}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                .font(.title2)
        }))
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSettings, content: {
            //Show view
            SettingsView(user: $user)
        })
        .onChange(of: scenePhase){ phase in
            if phase == .inactive {saveAction()}
        }
    }
```

This is the view titled "Expenses"

```
var body: some View {
        List{
            Section(header: Text("Current \(title)")) {
                HStack {
                    Text(month)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$\(balance)")
                }
                
                if title == TransactionType.income.rawValue {
                    let sources = getSourceAmount()
                    
                    if sources.count == 0 {
                        Text("No source income information.")
                    } else {
                        ForEach(sources, id:\.self) { source in
                            HStack {
                                Text("From \(source.name)")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$\(source.amount.round())")
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
            }
            
            
            Section(header: Text("Transactions")) {
                
                if transactions.count > 0 {
                    
                    ForEach(transactions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: TransactionDetailView(index: index)) {
                            TransactionRow(transaction: transactions[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    
                } else {
                    Text("No transactions for this month.")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    
    
}
```

This is the view that shows when you click on the transaction.

```
var body: some View {
    let transaction = transactions[index]
    
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Details")) {
            HStack {
                Text("Type")
                Spacer()
                Text(transaction.kind!)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Amount")
                Spacer()
                Text("$\(transaction.amount.round())")
            }
            
            if transaction.note != "" {
                HStack{
                    Text("Note")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.note!)
                }
                
            }
            
            if transaction.kind == TransactionType.income.rawValue {
                HStack {
                    Text("Source")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.source!)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Account")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.account!)
                }
            } else
            if transaction.kind == TransactionType.expense.rawValue {
                HStack {
                    Text("Category")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.category!)
                }
                
                if transaction.subcategory != "" {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Subcategory")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(transaction.subcategory!)
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Account")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.account!)
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Text("From")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.account!)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("To")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(transaction.toAccount!)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    .navigationTitle("\(transaction.date!.monthDayYear)")
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110142/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi so that does seem to be working. Appreciate it. Only thing is the button is staying highlighted after you move back one screen. I think it's because of that message I'm getting.